# C5.0 number of boosting iterations stops early

Tags: r

I assume this question has more to do with the back-end operations that I don't understand because this behavior *seems* odd, at least to me.

When I run a C5.0 model with an (albeit extreme) error matrix of:

`error_cost <- matrix(c(0, 1, 15, 0), nrow = 2)`

and 10 trials I get 10 iterations.

If I do everything the same and up the trials anywhere between 11 and 100 it stops early at 7 iterations, and the output, while "working", is garbage.

If I change the error matrix to:

`error_cost <- matrix(c(0, 1, 4, 0), nrow = 2)`

and up the iterations to 100 it iterates 100 times (and the results are really good).

Obviously my problem is in the error cost, but I'm just trying to understand **why** it causes it to behave this way. And while this is a real problem I'm working on, the error costs and iterations are more an attempt to understand what is happening under the hood.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Full code:

```
library(C50)

model_data_train$Donated <- as.factor(model_data_train$Donated)
model_data_test$Donated <- as.factor(model_data_test$Donated)

error_cost <- matrix(c(0, 4, 1, 0), nrow = 2)

dt_model10 <- C5.0(model_data_train[-113], model_data_train$Donated, 
                   trials = 100, 
                   rules = TRUE, costs = error_cost)
```

Comment: You haven't supplied any runable code so it's impossible for anyone to reproduce your results to test what might be going on. It's not ever clear what R package and functions you are using. Please edit your question to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: When you add a tag to a question, check the tooltip to make sure it is appropriate in the context of your question. That way it gets exposed to the right people. :)

Comment: I added as much code as I can. Also, I searched for more specific tags but nothing came up.

Comment: That's fine - just mentioned it because `boost` refers to the c++ libraries.

Comment: There's a earlyStopping option which you can set to FALSE if you want to have the exact number of boosting iterations.

Answer (score 0):

If you read deeper in the library documentation there is a control feature called earlyStopping which you can toggle off:

```
dt_model10 <- C5.0(model_data_train[-113], model_data_train$Donated, 
               trials = 100, 
               rules = TRUE, 
               costs = error_cost,
               control=C5.0Control(earlyStopping=FALSE))
```

as mentioned by @Kenston Choi