# How to do modify an existing function from a function?

Tags: r, methods, decision-tree

Im trying to increase the limit of trials parameter which is currently set  to 100 in C50 package. I tried to do this using fix.

```
library(C50)
data(churn)
fix(C5.0.default)  # i change the maxtrials <- 200
treeModel <- C5.0(x = churnTrain[, -20], y = churnTrain$churn, trials = 150)
```

Then i get the following error when trials are less than 200.

```
could not find function "makeNamesFile"
```

I restart R and then try using `fixInNamespace` and changed the trials to 200.

```
fixInNamespace("C5.0.default", pos="package:C50")    
treeModel <- C5.0(x = churnTrain[, -20], y = churnTrain$churn, trials = 150)
```

The model works for trials below 100 but gives a following error for trials above 100. This is the standard error that C5.0 gives when user inputs the trials above 100.

```
number of boosting iterations must be between 1 and 100
```

I want to increase no of trials(boosting) for C5 model. How do i do that? This might be an implementation constraint but since xgboost can handle more than 100 boosting iteration there might be a way for C5 to handle this.

I am able to increase the iteration to more than 100 with fix call. But the thing is that i need to run all the R scripts that are in source version of C50 package. What can i do to avoid this. I tried installing C50 package from the source and gave this a try but it didnt work out.

Comment: May I know, from where you got `CS50 package`?

Comment: Please explain what "doesnt[sic!] work" means. `fixInNamespace("C5.0.default", pos="package:C50")` works just fine on my system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017429/c5-0-number-of-boosting-iterations-stops-early/36050855#36050855

Comment: The generic is called `C5.0` not `C5`. How do you call the function?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Thus, you need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You do not need to uninstall. Just restart R.

Comment: I tried your example (first 4 lines, with the "fix" call). I cannot reproduce the problem, I got an error message saying that number of iterations must be between 1 and 200. Then I tried with "trials=180" and it worked - produced a result and gave no error.

Comment: It says "Number of boosting iterations: 180" and "cat(treeModel$output)" shows trials 0-179.

Comment: I have the same version. I get requested/actual 180. Frankly even though it seems to be working on my machine, editing code of package functions in sealed namespaces is not a good thing to do. It may be cleaner, yet more work indeed, to modify the package sources, build it and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I could get more than 100 trails by tweaking the source code from [this](https://github.com/topepo/C5.0/blob/master/pkg/C50_0.1.0-21.tar.gz) link. You need to source the R files, then you can change the default no of trails to get more than 100 trials.

```
# Allow for more than 100 Boosting
setwd('Path to R files')
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.R$")
lapply(files, source)
fix(C5.0.default)
```